# org-mode: Use dvisvgm on HTML export of Babel LaTeX blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-babel

As far as I understand, there are two competing forces when exporting LaTeX  to HTML.

1. If it's in the text (including using `\begin` blocks), then the preview mode of `org.el` is used, relying on `org-preview-latex-process-alist`.  If `#+OPTIONS: tex:dvisvgm` is specified, then this goes through `dvisvgm`, and things are of beauty. (Especially since I can add `--font-format=woff` to the options of `dvisvgm` and have embedded fonts.)
2. If it's in a Babel `#+BEGIN_SRC latex` block, then `ob-latex` takes the lead.  Instead of using `dvisvgm`, it uses `htlatex` in a arguably cumbersome way.

**My problem:** I like using Babel, but I want my LaTeX to be executed by `dvisvgm`.  Is there an easy solution?